# Extremely Simple Menu Question for Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a very simple question about menu control in Android. I'm writing a program that performs some simple numeric calculations and outputs an answer. My question is how do make the program move to second screen when a button is pressed, and how can I let the user move back to the original screen. 
Here's a quick example

Screen 1

```
"Add Numbers"

Input 1st # ____       
Input 2nd # ____      
(Add)
```

Screen 2

```
The answer is "____"
```

The user inputs two integers. presses add, and then the program moves to the second screen which displays the answer. If they user wants they can return to the first screen and start over.

I know this has been covered but with so many resources I don't know what to look for. Answers or links to resources would be most helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What platform, language and technologies are you using?  Console input/output, and C?  .NET WPF on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following layout for the screen to input numbers. Name the file first.xml.

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Input Ist:"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

 <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/first"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="250px"

   /> 

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/secondnumber"
         android:text = "Input 2nd"  
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="20px"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         />     

    <EditText 
              android:id="@+id/second"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="250px"

      /> 

     <Button 
          android:id="@+id/add_button"
              android:text="Add"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="15px"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

              /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

To add these numbers

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
         Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        EditText num1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
        EditText num2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.second);
}
```

The click listener code

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
                int n2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
                int result = n1 + n2;
                String res = Integer.toString(result);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
                                intent.putExtra("result", result); //Passing the result to the second activity using intent
                startActivity(intent);
                }
```

In the Result.java class.

```
public class Result extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
                String result = intent.getStringExtra("result");
                TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
                t1.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Most definitely. You've given me a direct example of exactly what I needed. This starting point helps me immensely. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

May I know what type of language are u using?
I recently just did it with C#.
My flow is that, when I start a program, it will auto be forced to the second screen, with some power options.

But if yours is just moving the program the diff screens, it will be easy in C#.

```
Screen Srn = Screen.PrimaryScreen; // gives your information of Primary Screen.

Screen[] Srn = Screen.AllScreens; //gives u an array of all your available screen( srn[0] is primary screen, etc)
```

So, using the intellisense from the IDE, should be able to get the width, height, etc.
Cant remember exactly, but something like src.width or src.bounds.width.

Easiest way to move your program will be to move the program x axis to the respective screen.

Answer (score 1):

ViewFlipper will work well. You could also try "startActivityForResult" to pass your answers to the next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) class. It works like tabs, but without the tabs UI. You can use an xml layout to display your 2 (or more) screens, and [showNext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#showNext())() or [showPrevious](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#showPrevious())() to flip between the screens.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links! I've now read the documentation and I'll be rereading it to get a full understanding.